# How to set min value DateTimeType [Symfony]

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I want to set the minimal date in input date

```
$builder->add('dateRdv', DateTimeType::class,['data'   => new \DateTime(),
                'attr'   => ['min' => new \DateTime()]])
```

Error is :

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class DateTime could not be
>   converted to string").

**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using Datetime as a string, as the error said, just format it into a string:

```
$builder->add('dateRdv', DateTimeType::class,['data'   => new \DateTime(),
                'attr'   => ['min' => ( new \DateTime() )->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')]]);
```