# Disable a future date using the Symfony DateType

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony5

I'm using Symfony 5 and I have a problem with my form.

How to disable dates in the future when I use a `DateType` with `'widget' => 'single-text'` and `js-datepicker`?
Note that I don't have access to the frontend, everything has to be done in the backend.
Here is what I currently have:

```
$builder->add('date', DateType::class, [
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'attr' => [
                'class' => 'js-datepicker'
            ]
        ]);
```

Thank you in advance for your answer!

Comment: I don't think it's possible. According to [this](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate) you can only set the `maxDate` in initialization of the plugin with a json object or after by setting the `maxDate` `option`.

Comment: I guess you could modify your form DateType to add a `max` attribute (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55243265/13013725)), but it will probably keep showing all the dates in your frontend datepicker plugin. You have to modify the frontend to do this or modify the plugin so it can read this max and min attribute to create the `maxDate` and `minDate` options in the plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you want to use HTML5 validation you can use the `max` attribute:

```
$builder->add('date', DateType::class, [
    'widget' => 'single_text',
    'attr' => [
        'class' => 'js-datepicker',
        'max' => date('Y-m-d')
    ]
]);
```

And if you want to make a backend validation you can use **Symfony Assert**
you can use `LessThan` or `LessThanOrEqual` (in case you want to include today date)

Inside your entity add this import:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
```

and then you can use `@Assert` :

```
/**
 * @Assert\LessThan("today")
 */
private $date;
```